# How to pass Boolean value to Htm5 video controls attribute by using React,JS-constructor(props)

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

```
class App extends React.Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
    
      // Calling super class constructor
      super(props);
        
      // Creating state
      this.state ={
        video.controls= true

      }
      
    }
     
    render() {
        return (
        
            <div className= "container">
                <video controls>
                <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
                </video>
            </div>
        );
    } }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as a note Controls in HTML5 video element is a boolean attribute:

> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

So the resulting HTML5 will either have 'controls' or not when you view it.

(https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes)

Setting it from the property passed is like this - e.g. using hooks (haven't tested this but adapted from similar code to reload source that I have tested so should be roughly correct):

```js
function InputVideo = (props) => {

  const setControls = () => {
    //Function to set controls
    let vidElement = ref.current;
    if (vidElement) {
      vidElement.controls = props.controlsSetting;
    }
  };

  useEffect (setControls, [props.controlsSetting]);

  return(
    <div className="video-wrapper">
        <video className="video-area" ref={ref}>
          <source src={props.source} type="video/mp4"/>
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
  )
});
```

For your example using classes, I think you are trying to make the controls attribute be rendered only if the property is true, so you could use something like:

```html
{props.videoControlsBoolean ? <video controls> : <video>}
```

i.e. if the videoControlsBoolean you pass in is true then include 'controls' in the video tag when you render it and if not then don't.